# Suma números por teclado

Tags: python, variables

estoy empezando a aprender Python por mi cuenta y tengo mal el ejercicio más simple del mundo... Consiste en pasar dos números por teclado y mostrar su suma, este es el código que tengo:

```
a = input()
b = input()
c = a + b
print(c)
```

El problema es que así me muestra un número al lado del otro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El comando input retorna lo ingresado por el usuario en forma de cadena. Cuando haces la suma, estás sumando cadenas, no numeros. Cuando haces "1"+"2" en Python, el resultado será "12", ya que estás concatenando "1" y "2". Para que sean números, tienes que convertir lo ingresado por el usuario en numeros.

```
a = input()
b = input()
c = int(a) + int(b)
print(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = int(input("Número 1: "))
b = int(input("Número 2: "))
c = a + b
print("\nEl resultado es ",c)
```

yo te recomiendo que cuando pides los datos le digas que es de tipo int y después si haces la operación normal a + b

Comment: En realidad, no le dices al input que sea de tipo int, mas bien conviertes el resultado del input (de tipo str) a tipo int.